# [itext]PdfReader failing on WAS8

Tags: java, pdf, itext

all.  I am attempting to use iText to get the page count of a PDF file.  The code is running from a web service on WAS8.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
int pageCount = reader.getNumberOfPages();
```

Very basic.  The problem is, as soon as I hit the PdfReader line, it blows up.  I get a "Source not found" error and the title bar on the tab says "JavaBeanDispatcher(JavaDispatcher).invokeTargetOperation(Method, Object[]) line: 106".

I imagine this is more of a Java setup issue than an iText issue, but I just can't figure it out.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out.  I was originally including the iText jar file in the project build path.  I changed it to include the jar file in the manifest.mf file instead and it worked.